# Case Statement in SQL Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a SQL query but an error happens when I run it.

Error:

> [Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]
>   The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row..
>   SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.19.49

This is the SQL query that I am trying to run, I believe there is a problem with my `CASE` statement, I'm running out of solution. Please help, thanks a lot!

```
SELECT 
    ES.SHPMNT_REF,
    (CASE 
        WHEN (ES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME) IS NULL
           THEN (SELECT BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME 
                 FROM BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND 
                 WHERE BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF)
           ELSE (ES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME)
     END) AS SP
FROM 
    BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES
WHERE 
    ES.DATE_CREATE > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS
```

Comment: Instead of selecting _inside_ of `CASE`, you should join `BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT` with `BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND`

Comment: Your subquery (`SELECT BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME from...`) returns more than one row, but you're trying to use it at row-level in the query. Do you have multiple records in the `BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND` table with the same `SHPMNT_REF` value? If so you need to rethink how you're retrieving the `SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME` value.

Comment: Your `WHERE` has some invalid syntax too. I assume `CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS` should actually be `DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`?

Comment: @mshsayem Thanks bro! it's work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after. Joining on the table data you might need, then letting COALESCE check for null and get the other data if it is.

```
SELECT 
    ES.SHPMNT_REF,
    COALESCE(ES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME, OH.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME) AS SP
FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES
    LEFT JOIN BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND AS OH 
        ON ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF
WHERE 
    ES.DATE_CREATE > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put inside the case:

```
THEN (SELECT TOP 1 BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because your subquery returns multiple values.
The best way would be joining the two table first and then get the value you need when the value is NULL.
That should work:

```
SELECT 
    ES.SHPMNT_REF
    ,CASE
       WHEN ES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME IS NULL
         THEN EO.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME 
       ELSE ES.SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME
     END AS 'SP'
FROM BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES
LEFT JOIN BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND EO
ON ES.SHPMNT_REF = EO.SHPMNT_REF

WHERE ES.DATE_CREATE > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS
```